# Ensure minimum distance between two elements

Tags: spacing

Context: I'm typesetting a songbook in which there are occasionally "chords" typeset above one word, i.e. if I type someting like

```
This \chord{A}is my \chord{B}beautiful song
```

I'll get something that visually looks like that:

```
     A     B
This is my beautiful song
```

I have no difficulty doing that with essentially a combination of `\raise` and `\hss`. However, sometimes, when the `\chord` commands are too close together, the chords are typeset above one another (normal, they occupy no space):

```
This \chord{Am}i\chord{B7m}s \chord{C7}a mess
```

When I typeset this, the `Am`, `B7m` and `C7` overlap to some extent.

My question is then: how can I make sure they don't overlap ? In other words, I'd like to insert a space before the chord is typeset long enough that it is positioned after the previous space has been flushed.

For the record, the definition of `\chord` is

```
\leavevmode\raise2.3ex\hbox to 0pt{\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}#1\hss
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\chord}[1]{\leavevmode\raise2.3ex\hbox to 0pt{\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}#1\hss}}

\begin{document}
This \chord{A}is my \chord{B}beautiful song

This \chord{Am}i\chord{B7m}s \chord{C7}a mess

% I'd like something that looks about like this, but automatically
This \chord{Am}i\hspace{5mm}\chord{B7m}s \hspace{5mm}\chord{C7}a mess

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know about packages like `leadsheets`?

Comment: @clemens leadsheets does not seem to solve directly my problem, but it looks like something I should have had a look at before anyway. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to change the input slightly. That is, instead of just supplying the chord to the macro `\chord`, supply the chord *and* the letter coverage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\chord}[1]{\leavevmode\raise2.3ex\hbox to 0pt{\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}#1\hss}}
\newcommand{\newchord}[2]{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
    \scriptsize #1 \\ \strut#2
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
This \chord{A}is my \chord{B}beautiful song

This \chord{Am}{i}\chord{B7m}s \chord{C7}a mess

% I'd like something that looks about like this, but automatically
This \chord{Am}i\hspace{5mm}\chord{B7m}s \hspace{5mm}\chord{C7}a mess

\hrulefill

This \newchord{A}{is} my \newchord{B}{beautiful} song

This \newchord{Am}{i}\newchord{B7m}{s} \newchord{C7}{a} mess

\end{document}
```

The `tabular` structure will expand to fit the widest length (chord or letter).

Comment: This is of course a possibility, but, unfortunately, that would mean going again through a rather large number of songs that were already typeset... So upvoting, but I can't accept as it does not solve my problem !